# Duplicated headers in ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-headers

I'm returning an ResponseEntity for file download.

```
@RequestMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download(){
    byte[] fileContent = manager.getFile();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.setPragma("cache");
    headers.setExpires(0);
    headers.setCacheControl("private");
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "sample.pdf");
    headers.setContentLength(fileContent.length);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(fileContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

In chrome I following request headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="attachment"; filename="sample-pdf.pdf"
Content-Length:1469
Content-Type:application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 15 Aug 2013 08:10:25 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:cache
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

If I do it in the old way using HttpServletResponse

```
public void download(HttpServletResponse response){
    byte[] fileContent = manager.getFile();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "private");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.pdf");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(fileContent, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

The header is what I wanted

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="attachment"; filename="sample-pdf.pdf"
Content-Length:1469
Content-Type:application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 15 Aug 2013 08:10:25 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Is there any way to clean up the http headers value when using `ResponseEntity`?

Answer (score 0):

do not use

```
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "sample.pdf");
```

or other set's

only use add methods like:

```
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"sample_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf\"");
```